# How to detect if Intent was started by my app

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, android-alertdialog

I have a class which basically listens for all the outgoing call intents and shows the user a dialogue box.
If the user clicks yes, then I let him complete the call using his phone network by making a CALL intent and firing it.

Now, whenever, this custom call intent is fired, my listener also again gets fired obviously and it shows the dialog box. I want to know, in my Broadcast Receiver listener, how can I identity if the outgoing call was made via my app or some other app.

I tried passing an extra key-value parameter in my custom call intent but in the listner, that key-value entry was missing.

**BroadcastReceiver Listner**

```
    public class CallListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            String phoneNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            if(intent.getExtras().containsKey("myapp"))
                Log.e("randomstring"," key present " +phoneNumber);
            else
                Log.e("randomstring","key absent "+phoneNumber); // always absent even if I add if before starting call intent.
            if (phoneNumber != null) {
                setResultData(null);
                setResultCode(0);
                Intent intentvar = new Intent(context, OutgoingCall.class);
                intentvar.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                context.startActivity(intentvar);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity Class to show dialog box**

```
    public class OutgoingCall extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        displayAlert();
    }

    private void displayAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_DarkActionBar);
        builder.setMessage("Do you really want to call him/her?").setCancelable(
                false).setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        String url = "tel:00000000"; //need to pass the number via intent extras.
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(url));
                        intent.putExtra("myapp", true);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }
}
```